# Why was I unable to use the very low quality flag?

Tags: bug, support

Today I encountered a GDSE question that was not in English.
As per [this guidance on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262015/950488) I tried to flag it as `Very Low Quality`. As a result, I got a popup message stating:

```
You don't have the permission to use this type of flag.
```

I went through my flagging history and  I found that I was able to use this flag previously on:

- Jan 15, 2018 at 23:08
- Aug 6, 2016 at 19:10
- May 25, 2016 at 10:50

Also, if it matters, I have enough rep to access the low quality posts review queue.

I found [this potentially related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233560/228147) post on SO.Meta, however the post I was trying to flag hadn't been deleted. It is possible that I flagged it as or just after it was closed. The system did let me flag it as `in need of moderator intervention`.

Is this an error? Have the reputation requirements for using VLQ flags changed? Or did is this a matter of my bad timing & the system giving a misleading message?

Comment: I just tried to use that flag on the question. I can't; it's not offered to me (usually, whether I am a mod does not make a difference for this kind of site feature). I suspect you tried to flag the question after it was closed. FWIW, I think the site is usually "smart enough" to not present an option that is not available to you. I think the "bug" here is that there is not a more specific error message for this situation.